# Ada 2005 access type

Tags: ada

I am trying to solve a differential equation with Euler's method using the technique employed with the access type shown in *Ben Ari second editions of Ada for Software Engineers*, Section 13.6.1 starting on Page 263.

I have modified the differential equation given in the book to dy/dx = 2*x*y with Initial Condition y(x=1) = 1. The increment is h = 0.1 and I have to find output the values of y(1), y(1.1), y(1.2), y(1.3), y(1.4) and y(1.5).

There are 3 Ada files: diff.adb which is the main file, euler.ads and euler.adb.

The file **diff.adb** is

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Euler;
procedure Diff is

  type Real is digits 6;
  type Vector is array(Integer range <>) of Real;
  type Ptr is access function (X: Real; Y: Real) return Real;

  procedure Solve is new Euler(Real, Vector, Ptr);

  function Ident(X: Real; Y: Real) return Real is
  begin
    return 2.0*X*Y;
  end Ident;

  package Real_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO(Real);
  use Real_IO;

  Answer: Vector(1..10);

begin
  Solve(Ident'Access, 1.0, 0.1, Answer);
  for N in Answer'Range loop
    Put(1.0 + 0.1 * Real(N-1), Exp => 0);
    Put( Answer(N), Exp => 0);
    Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
  end loop;
end Diff;
```

The file **euler.ads** is

```
--
-- Solving a differential equation.
-- Demonstrates generic floating point type.
--
generic
  type Float_Type is digits <>;
  type Vector is array(Integer range <>) of Float_Type;
  type Function_Ptr is access function (X: Float_Type; Y: Float_Type) return Float_Type;
procedure Euler(
  F: in Function_Ptr; Init, H: in Float_Type; Result: out Vector);
```

And the file **euler.adb** is

```
procedure Euler(
  F: in Function_Ptr; Init, H: in Float_Type; Result: out Vector) is
begin
  Result(Result'First) := Init;
  for N in Result'First+1..Result'Last loop
    Result(N) := Result(N-1) + H * F(Result(N-1));
  end loop;
end Euler;
```

When I compile **diff.adb**, I get the error message:

euler.adb: Builder results
euler.adb:6:36
missing argument for parameter Y

As I don't understand access types well, I would be very grateful if I can get help making the above codes work.

PS: The results to be outputtted should be as follows when worked out by hand and a calculator:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1.1 | 1.2 |
| 1.2 | 1.464 |
| 1.3 | 1.815360 |
| 1.4 | 2.287354 |
| 1.5 | 2.927813 |

The first column gives the x values (with an increment of 0.1) and the second column gives the ouput of the Euler method (y values).

**After Simon's help:**

I used Simon's code for euler.adb:

This was changed to Simon's code:

```
procedure Euler
  (F : in Function_Ptr; Init, H : in Float_Type; Result : out Vector)
is
      Step : constant Float_Type := H;
   
     Current_X : Float_Type := 1.0;
begin
   Result (Result'First) := Init;
   for N in Result'First + 1 .. Result'Last loop
      Current_X := Current_X + Step;
      Result (N) := Result (N - 1) + Step * F (Current_X, Result (N - 1));
   end loop;
end Euler;
```

The initial value of X is 1.0 and it is 1.0 as well for Y. In diff.adb, the output line Put(0.1 * Real(N-1), Exp => 0) has been changed to Put(1.0 + 0.1 * Real(N-1), Exp => 0) so as to get the sequence 1.0 to 1.5 (with also the line  Answer: Vector(1..6) accordingly modified from 10 to 6).

When I run the corrected code I now get:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00000 |
| 1.1 | 1.22000 |
| 1.2 | 1.51280 |
| 1.3 | 1.90613 |
| 1.4 | 2.43984 |
| 1.5 | 3.17180 |

The Y values from the above table are not OK as compared with the values from the table given up earlier.
For instance by hand calculation, Y(1.1)= 1 + 0.1 * 2.0 * 1 * 1 = 1.2 where I am using the equation Y1 = Y0 + h*f(X0, Y0) with Y0 and X0 as the initial values of 1 both and h is the X increment of 0.1. Then Y(1.2) = 1.2 + 0.1 * 2 * 1.1 * 1.2 = 1.464000 where I used the equation Y2 = Y1 + h * f(X1, Y1) with X1 = X0 + h = 1 + 0.1 = 1.1 and Y1 has been calculated in the previous iteration as Y(X=1.1)=1.2. Then we can continue calculating for Y(X=1.3), Y(X=1.4) and Y(X=1.5) in a similar manner.

Comment: The compiler error indicates the call to `F` should have 2 parameters, but you only have one (and the name of the missing parameter is `Y`). But I can't see the definition of `F` or `Result`, so can't help more than that.

Comment: I have put the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reworking of `euler.adb`, which at least gets you a compilation.

I’d strongly recommend more meaningful names; `H` may be OK in a maths textbook (or Wikipedia!) but it hardly helps a non-mathematical maintainer. Also, I reformatted the code (using `gnatpp`) to be closer to normal practice.

```ada
procedure Euler
  (F : in Function_Ptr; Init, H : in Float_Type; Result : out Vector)
is
   --  renamed for clarity
   Step : constant Float_Type := H;
   
   --  Init is the initial Y, I think, so what's the initial value of
   --  X?  guessing here ...
   Current_X : Float_Type := 0.0;
begin
   Result (Result'First) := Init;
   for N in Result'First + 1 .. Result'Last loop
      Current_X := Current_X + Step;
      Result (N) := Result (N - 1) + Step * F (Current_X, Result (N - 1));
   end loop;
end Euler;
```

Results:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00000 | 1.00000 |
| 0.10000 | 1.02000 |
| 0.20000 | 1.06080 |
| 0.30000 | 1.12445 |
| 0.40000 | 1.21440 |
| 0.50000 | 1.33584 |
| 0.60000 | 1.49615 |
| 0.70000 | 1.70561 |
| 0.80000 | 1.97850 |
| 0.90000 | 2.33463 |

Comment: I can program without the use of access type but the example from Ben Ari book captivated my attention in how the access type (which is new to me) can be used. The initial value of Y is 1.0 and so is the initial value of X. Thus Y(X=1) = 1. I have changed my original code accordingly to compute Y(X=1.1), Y(X=1.2), Y(X=1.3), Y(X=1.4) and Y(X=1.5) but the results are not OK as compared to the correct results.

Comment: See amended post with some more explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that if you put the line that updates `Current_X` *after* the line that sets `Result (N)` you might get the same answer as your hand-calculated one. But, is that _right_? What would Euler do?

Comment: Yes indeed, that was the mistake. The X value was updated too soon! I was so focussed on the "access" stuff that I oversaw what the code was doing! I would like to know if possible where to get a good introduction to access types. I need more examples involving calculations as I've posted above. Thank you.

Comment: When I'm using "type Real is digits 6", does that mean that say when Y(X=1.4) is calculated as 2.287354, is it this truncated value to 6 S.F. which is being used in calculating the next Y i.e. Y(X=1.5) in the next iteration? This is important since when we work out the problem by hand calculation, we keep intermediate results only to a certain number of S.F. e.g. 6 in this case. On the other hand in a computer program with just "Float" then more S.F. will be used which may not give the same results if step by step calculations are made by hand and keeping say only 6 S.F. at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your function takes two arguments, but you've only supplied one of them:

```
  function Ident(X: Real; Y: Real) return Real is
```

```
F(Result(N-1));
```

Comment: The function uses two variables x and y. The output from the Euler's method is y.